# mysql parameter to allow insert an empty string instead of NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache

In my database tables there are fiels which can be NULL of different types: *integer*, *date*, *datetime*, etc.

The first of our computer treats well this code:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (..., '', '', ...)
INSERT INTO table VALUES (..., NULL, NULL, ...)
```

The second one treats only code with **NULL**, but gives error with empty string.

I wonder, how to change MySQL parameters to force the second one work properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  You are getting different behaviors on different servers?

Comment: So just pass in the `NULL` values.  That is the correct way to set things to `NULL`.  An empty string (Oracle aside) is not equivalent to NULL.

Comment: Yes I can just pass `NULL`, but I don't want to change all occurances of this. This is an ugly code that we have to maintain :(

Comment: Exactly, different behaviors on different *local* servers.

Comment: Add a before insert trigger to replace '' with NULL?  It's the only thing I can think of without actually fixing the problem.  This addresses the symptom only.